# Proving given sets are mathematical intervals

Tags: proof-writing

Let’s assume we have a subset of real numbers called $S$. We call the set of upper bounds of $S$, $U$ and we call its set of lower bounds, $L$.

If we define a set called $G$ that consists of any real number not included in the sets $S$, $U$ and $L$, how could we prove that $U$, $L$ and especially, $S \cup G$ are all mathematical **intervals**?

Comment: Hint. $S\cup G\subseteq [a,b]$ for $a\in L$ and $b\in U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the definition.  That is, to prove $X$ is an interval, suppose $a,b \in X$ and $a < c < b.$  Then show $c \in X.$

For $L,$ show that $c < b$ and $b \in L$ implies $c \in L.$

$U$ is similar to $L.$

For $S \cup G,$ show that $c < b$ and $b \in S \cup G$ implies $c \not\in U.$   Similarly, $a < c$ and $a \in S \cup G$ implies $c \not\in L.$  Conclude $c \in S \cup G.$